# Opacity in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used `html2canvas` library to render html to canvas. I have a problem when used it, as I get the following error :

```
html2canvas.js:3130 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of null
at NodeContainer.StackingContext (http://dicprj.moe/wp-content/plugins/iii-dictionary/chat/pad/lib/js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js:3130:52)
at NodeParser.newStackingContext (http://dicprj.moe/wp-content/plugins/iii-dictionary/chat/pad/lib/js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js:1991:17)
at NodeParser.<anonymous> (http://dicprj.moe/wp-content/plugins/iii-dictionary/chat/pad/lib/js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js:2003:18)
at Array.forEach (native)
at NodeParser.createStackingContexts (http://dicprj.moe/wp-content/plugins/iii-dictionary/chat/pad/lib/js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js:1999:16)
at NodeParser.<anonymous> (http://dicprj.moe/wp-content/plugins/iii-dictionary/chat/pad/lib/js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js:1845:14)
at http://dicprj.moe/wp-content/plugins/iii-dictionary/chat/pad/lib/js/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js:3318:25
```

**This is my code :**

```js
jQuery("#homework-content > div").each(function(i,v){
  console.log(jQuery(this)[0]);
  html2canvas(jQuery(this)[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    allowTaint : true
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10 homework-content math-type-15" id="homework-content">   
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question" id="flashcard-q1">
  <span class="math-number">8X + 1 = 0 <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="- 1/8" name="result[q1]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text">
        </span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q2">
  <span class="math-number">1X + 3 =  1 <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="-2" name="result[q2]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q3">
  <span class="math-number">4X - 9  = 2 <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="2 3/4" name="result[q3]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q4">
  <span class="math-number">6X +  8  = 3 <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="- 5/6" name="result[q4]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q5">
  <span class="math-number">10X - 7  =  4 <br> X =</span>
     <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="1 1/9" name="result[q5]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q6">
  <span class="math-number">7X  + 2 =  5 <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="3/7" name="result[q6]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q7">
  <span class="math-number">8X + 4  = 6 <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="1/4" name="result[q7]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q8">
  <span class="math-number">9X -  3  =  7 <br> X =</span>
     <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="1 1/9" name="result[q8]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q9">
  <span class="math-number">3X  -  0   =   8  <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="2 2/3" name="result[q9]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q10">
  <span class="math-number">9X  +   1  =  9    <br> X =</span>
  <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="8/9" name="result[q10]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
  <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q11">
   <span class="math-number">2X  +  3  =  10   <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="3 1/2" name="result[q11]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q12">
   <span class="math-number">7X       +       7       =       0       <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="-1" name="result[q12]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q13">
   <span class="math-number">9X  +  5  =  1  <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="- 4/9" name="result[q13]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q14">
   <span class="math-number">6X   +   2    =   0 <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="- 1/3" name="result[q14]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q15">
   <span class="math-number">6X +  5  =   1  <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="- 2/3" name="result[q15]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q16">
   <span class="math-number">3X -   9  =   2  <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="3 2/3" name="result[q16]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q17">
   <span class="math-number">2X    + 7   =  3 <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="-2" name="result[q17]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q18">
      <span class="math-number">1X - 4  = 4  <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="8" name="result[q18]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q19">
   <span class="math-number">2X + 0  =  5  <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="2 1/2" name="result[q19]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flashcard-question equation-question hidden" id="flashcard-q20">
   <span class="math-number">7X  +  4  =  6 <br> X =</span>
   <span class="math-number input-box"><input data-answer="2/7" name="result[q20]" class="answer-box" autocomplete="off" type="text"></span>
   <span class="math-number"></span>
  </div>
       
</div>
```

The problem :

- It is **just canvas first div**, other div will appear with an error : `Cannot read property 'opacity' of null`
- The performance of html2canvas is slow, how can I fix it ?

Comment: Having same issue... Do you find any solution for that?